# Entity Framework & Linq performance problem

Tags: c#, linq, performance, entity-framework

I have a performance problem with Entity Framework and Linq, when paging a list of Product objects:

```
var data =_service.GetAll(); 
var page = data.Skip((index) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
list.Add(page.AsEnumerable); // ** its slow right here
```

There are 1958 products in my test database, but when the above code runs I can see 3916 (that's 1958 *2) separate queries executed (by looking at the sql profiler).

The Product class looks something like:

```
public class Product 
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string ProductCode {get;set;}
    //..etc other properties
    public virtual ICollection<WarehouseProduct> WarehouseProducts { // etc }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { // etc }
    // etc other navigation properties
}
```

In the sql profiler I can see this query executed 3916 times:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
// etc
FROM [dbo].[WarehouseProducts] AS [Extent1]
```

What have I done wrong?  The Product object has 12 different navigation properties, but it was only WarehouseProduct was queried 3916 times.  Note that there is no WHERE clause on that query, but there is a foreign key relationship between the two tables (that's why it is a navigation property)

Comment: Are you sure it is executed twice, and you're not just watching at duplicate lines in the form of BeginExec/EndExec?

Comment: Thanks, you are correct - it is showing SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:BatchEnding in the profile, so it is 1958 queries.  But that still doesnt explain why it is executed once for every product, and without any where clause.

Comment: Could you post the code of the GetAll method ?

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard to tell whats happening with the actual query inside a black box.

Comment: `service.GetAll()` calls `repository.GetAll()` which just does `return ObjectSet.AsQueryable();`

Comment: The funny thing is that I did not see any `SELECT ... FROM dbo.Products` sql statement when looking at the profiler.  I just searched the whole output for dbo.Products, and it wasn't there.

Answer (score 3):

You must be accessing `Product.WarehouseProducts` after you get the products, so
if you're using Entities, you want to use `Products.Include("WarehouseProduct").Include("InvoiceLine")`
inside your `GetAll()` method, which will tell Entities to retrieve the data in the same query.

Related entities are lazy-loaded by default, so if you don't use `Include()` to specify which related entities to include in your results, then each time you access the related entity in your code, you will trigger another database lookup.

Comment: could you explain to the non-EF experts how that helps?

Comment: I've edited the question to show exactly where the sql queries occur (marked as "** its slow right here").  I haven't accessed Product.WarehouseProducts at all - that's why I cant understand all the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `page.AsEnumerable` is causing the queried sequence to be evaluated and materialized. The previous statements, assuming Lazy Loading is still enabled and you are querying an SQL data source, are setting up the conditions that will make up the SQL statement to execute.

You didn't post the GetAll() method, so that may be the source of your additional records.

The SQL query that was generated should have a TOP as part of the select, and it should be returning an resultset with multiple records, so you may not be profiling the correct query.